# Find indices of array elements that fulfill a condition

Tags: ruby

I have an array, and I need an array of subscripts of the original array's elements that satisfy a certain condition.

`map` doesn't do because it yields an array of the same size. `select` doesn't do because it yields references to the individual array elements, not their indices. I came up with the following solution:

```
my_array.map.with_index {|elem,i| cond(elem) ? i : nil}.compact
```

If the array is large and only a few elements fulfill the conditions, another possibility would be

```
index_array=[]
my_array.each_with_index {|elem,i| index_array << i if cond(elem)}
```

Both work, but isn't there a simpler way?

Comment: could you please share a sample array?

Comment: I guess technically `my_array.map.with_index {|elem,i| cond(elem) ? i : nil}.compact` could be simplified to `my_array.map.with_index {|elem,i| i if cond(elem)}.compact` but it is essentially the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, there is nothing inbuilt or much simpler that what you already got.

Variation:

```
my_array.each_with_index.with_object([]) do |(elem, idx), indices|
  indices << idx if cond(elem)
end
```

Comment: 1. Consider using `with_object` rather than `inject` to use _the same array_, instead of recreating it on each iteration. 2. Also, `do |(elem, idx), indices|`.

Answer (score 3):

Another possible alternative:

```
my_array.select.with_index {|elem, _| cond(elem) }.map(&:last)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Array#each_index](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-each_index) with select

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]
arr.each_index.select {|i| arr[i].odd? }
# => [0, 2]
```

Comment: This is way worse than `each.with_index.with_object` because it performs array index lookup on each iteration.